# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error(HttpProtocol)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, webserver, wia

I Programmed A WCF Service But I Have Some Error About HttpProtocol Please Help me

[Error That Captured From Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Nb8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly you forgot `<system.webServer>` parent tag,

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol

Like,

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```